# How to get AppRoleId in azure using graph api, roles are imported from aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We setup AWS single Account Access in azure active directory and configured all the settings that includes import roles from AWS account too using graph API.

Created group and added members to the group. Now we want to assign roles to the group that are imported from AWS. I am able to do that manually. I need to use graph API for that.

Not able to find the ID of role that are imported.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/appRoleAssignments](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup-id%7D/appRoleAssignments)

```
{
  "id": "id-of-role",
  "principalId": "objectId-of-group",
  "resourceId": "objectId-of-application"
}
```

Comment: Are these Azure AD roles or Azure RBAC roles?

Comment: I guess it is RBAC. We created this role in AWS and not in Azure.I may be wrong. New to Azure. for me it is not RBAC, not AD and not APP roles. like provisioning roles from third party app

Comment: Can you please confirm the type of role? Azure AD roles are for managing Azure AD (users, groups, applications etc.) whereas Azure RBAC roles are for managing Azure Resources (VMs, Storage accounts etc.). Please see this link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/what-s-the-difference-between-azure-roles-and-azure-ad-roles/ba-p/2363647. For Azure AD roles you would use Graph API whereas for Azure RBAC roles you would Azure Resource Manager API (essentially two different APIs).

Comment: Azure AD app roles, I confirm

Comment: Great. So if I understand correctly, you would want to find the ids of the roles for your application. Can you edit your question and include some screenshots of what you're doing manually currently that you would want to do through API?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri
 Found a way now to fetch the roles. after hours of digging. My way of finding solution is not good I guess

Comment: `My way of finding solution is not good I guess ` - No, this is the correct way.

Comment: Hi, can you please mark your own answer as answered, Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a way to get all the application app roles

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{application-object=id}/appRoles
```